# How do I get all lines of output when running command with exec.Cmd.Run()?

Tags: go, command, output, stdout

I'm using [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) to manage dependencies on my project. I created a script that runs `go test $(glide novendor)` (which tests all directories, excluding the *vendor/* one) for me. While it works, the output for the run command doesn't go beyond the 1st line:

`ok     my/project/scripts    0.005s`

Here is the portion of the script that runs it:

```go
// Get the paths to test (excluding the "vendor/" directory)
cmd := exec.Command("glide", "novendor")
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Could not run `glide novendor`: ", err)
}
glidenovendor := []string{"test"}
// Represents the "test ./src/... ./scripts/..." portion of the command
glidenovendor = append(glidenovendor, strings.Split(out.String(), " ")...)

// Run `go test ./src/... ./scripts/...`
cmd = exec.Command("go", glidenovendor...)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Could not run `go test` command with args: ", cmd, err)
}
```

Running the command directly on my shell gives me all lines of out put as expected.

How do I make my script print the entire output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that line

`glidenovendor = append(glidenovendor, strings.Split(out.String(), " ")...)`

for some reason added a new line character `"\n"` to the last string element of the `glidenovendor` slice. I still have no idea why. But removing it with the *snippet below* got the script running as expected:

```go
// Remove trailing LF from strings in `glidenovendor`
for i, v := range glidenovendor {
    glidenovendor[i] = strings.Trim(v, "\n")
}
```